# Slide a div every 2 seconds

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made a section just like the one in the link below. It contains 4 similar divs in the same position (3 are hidden and the first one is shown). I want each div to automatically slide every 2 seconds and show the div next to it (using jQuery and CSS3)
Here is a link showing an image of the section:

[image]

```
<div class="section">
     <div class="box"> 
        <div> Item 1 </div>
        <div> Item 2 </div>
        <div> Item 3 </div>
        <div> Item 4 </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: Use Bootstrap or owl Carousel!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lib like **slick-carousel**

https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

```js
$('.box').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>


<div class="section">
     <div class="box"> 
        <div> Item 1 </div>
        <div> Item 2 </div>
        <div> Item 3 </div>
        <div> Item 4 </div>
     </div>
</div>
```